# Web service gives exception

Tags: android, web-services

I pass Emailbody in my web sevice:

```
String emailBody="<span style='font-size: 14px;font-family:" +
                        " Arial;'>Following task is now completed.<table width=" +
                        "'100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td style=" +
                        "'height: 2px; background-color:'></td></tr>" +
                        "</table><p>"+remark+"</p> " +
                        "Completion Date: "+fmdate+"<br /><br /><br /><i>Note: This is automated message. Please do not reply to this email. If you have questions, please contact your Care Team Members.</i></span>";
```

My code for web Serivce is:

```
ProgressDialog Dialog;
boolean flag;
String call_method,method1;
HttpClient client;
XmlPullParserFactory factory;
HttpResponse res;
XmlPullParser parser;

@Override
protected Result doInBackground(String...value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("submit", "Login");

    method1=value[0];
    call_method=value[1];
    method1=removeSpace(method1);
    method1=removePlus(method1);
    String method=variable.host+call_method+method1;
    Log.d("method","==>"+method);

    HttpGet get;
    try {
        get=new HttpGet(new URI(method));
        //get=new HttpGet(new URI(URLEncoder.encode( method , "UTF8" )));

        res =LogInActivity.client.execute(get);



        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);  
        Log.i("Bhavik","Response : "+res.getStatusLine().toString());

        parser = factory.newPullParser(); 
        parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(res.getEntity().getContent()));   

        Log.d("Bhavik", "In Side HTTP "+call_method);


        if(call_method.equals("SaveMesage?")){

            System.out.println("hello world");

        }else{
            Messge_Detail_parser pd=new Messge_Detail_parser();
            flag=pd.replyData(parser);

        }


    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
   return null;

}
```

My Exception is :-

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 231:
```

Please help me how to pass Html tags in web serivce.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you are passing html content, I think you should just pass simple data and your web service will manage that code in html.

Comment: +1 for this question, once i had same problem and tried to solve please have a look on answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi have a try with Try  `HTML.fromhtml()` or `URLEncoder.encode(String)` and also make sure that in yours current String please  check the character at position 232, if it is to be a unwanted  unnecessary white space this error may occur. Replace the unwanted  unnecessary  white spaces by using trim function on yours string data.

Comment: If i use - emailBody = URLEncoder.encode(emailBody, "UTF-8"); then webservice do not give exception but my message display will not proper.  and if i use Html.fromHtml(emailBody, new ImageGetter(), null); then same web service gives exception of java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 231: